# grep for multiple patterns with options for each patterns

Tags: bash, sorting, sed, awk, grep

I have this file data.txt

```
BODY1
someval11
someval12

BODY2
someval21

BODY3
someval31
someval32
someval33

BODY1
someval111
someval112

BODY2
someval221

BODY3
someval331
someval332
someval333
```

and I want to extract **BODY1** paragraph and next 2 rows  and **BODY3** paragraph and next 3 rows, in this way:

```
BODY1
someval11
someval12

BODY3
someval31
someval32
someval33

BODY1
someval111
someval112

BODY3
someval331
someval332
someval333
```

the perfect line for this could be `grep -e "Body1" -A 2 -e "Body3" -A 3`, but it doesn't work. There is any way to do this with grep?.

I've solved this in this way:

```
 grep "Body1" -A 2 -n data.txt > out1.dat
 grep "Body3" -A 3 -n data.txt > out2.dat
 cat out2.dat >> out1.dat
 sed 's/://g' out1.dat | sed 's/-//g' | sort -n
```

but is there any easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/BODY[13]/,/^$/' file
```

**or**

```
awk '$1~"BODY[13]"' RS= ORS='\n\n' file
```

**Note:** The second answer *has* trailing newline.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^BODY[13]/,/^$/p' inputfile
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
BODY1
someval11
someval12

BODY3
someval31
someval32
someval33

BODY1
someval111
someval112

BODY3
someval331
someval332
someval333
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^BODY[13]$/{N;N;/^BODY3$/N;G;p}'  file
```